# Is there anything I can try to access this external hard drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I'm trying to access a friend's 1TB WD My Passport NTFS external hard drive. My Windows PC kept freezing. So I tried my MacBook Pro.

I installed FUSE:

```
brew cask install osxfuse
```

I tried:

```
$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
$ diskutil eject /dev/disk2
Disk /dev/disk2 ejected
$ diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2
One or more volume(s) failed to mount
$ diskutil mountDisk readOnly /dev/disk2
One or more volume(s) failed to mount
$ diskutil unmount /dev/disk2s1
disk2s1 was already unmounted
$ diskutil eject /dev/disk2s1
Disk /dev/disk2s1 ejected
$ diskutil mount /dev/disk2s1
Volume on disk2s1 timed out waiting to mount
$ diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk2s1
Volume on disk2s1 timed out waiting to mount
```

I tried:

```
$ brew install ntfs-3g
$ sudo mkdir /Volumes/NTFS
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/NTFS -olocal -oallow_other
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Resource busy
Failed to read vcn 0x0: Resource busy
Failed to open $Secure: No such file or directory
Failed to mount '/dev/disk2s1': No such file or directory
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: First test would be put it in another external case; eliminate that as a cause.

Comment: You don’t need FUSE and third-party drivers. MacOS has native read support for NTFS volumes.